# How do i redirect user to a error page when there is an error?

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to know how can i redirect users to an error page when there is an error with the code.

below are the error which i m trying to redirect

Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_PARSE)
syntax error, unexpected 'dd' (T_STRING)

or when a page is not valid or when there is an undefined variable

I have tried adding the following commands in app/Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{

  if ($exception instanceof CustomException) {
      dd('hi');
  }

  if ($exception instanceof ModelNotFoundException or $exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
    dd('hi1');
  }

  return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

and also have tried bellow

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        if ($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {
            dd('hi2);
        }
    }
}
```

But i m still getting the error message. How can i do it so that all error will be redirected to an error page (for now i will just see the dd() instate of redirecting to the page)

Comment: have u checked by changing APP_DEBUG = false in .env file

Comment: @Shibon i have tried but it is not showing me the dd('hi') or so

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dd('hi')` my whole app I spend the time looking at the exception handling.

When prepending `dd($e);`

in the `renderForConsole()` method, before line

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L467

than all relevant information is printed out.

This helped me to find the error reletively fast. Maybe this is helpfull for anyone in the meantime, although it's a terrible dump of the whole application state, but was extremely helpful for me, as the stacktrace is contained.

Comment: I will happy if it will be helpful for you!!

Comment: yup i have reviewed your code and also did some research more and manage to fix it already. thanks

Comment: just you can put like answer that another people can see. Thanks!!